# Persistant bag/set with direct access to known elements

Tags: ds.data-structures

I'm looking for a bag or set data structure that will allow for the following operations:

- **Add** an element to the set, and get a "pointer" to that element.

  `Add :: mystructure a -> a -> (mystructure a, myptr a)`
- **Remove** an element for which I have a "pointer".

  `Remove :: mystructure a -> myptr a -> mystructure a`
- **Enumerate** all the elements in the set.
  `Enumerate :: mystructure a -> [a]`

Note that I don't really care about duplicate values (the values I enter are already unique), nor the order of elements.

A very simple implementation for this structure would be to use a doubly-linked list, with the standard **Add** returning a pointer to the newly created list node, the standard **Remove** removing such a node from the list, and **Enumerate** simply traversing the list.

However, I need the structure to be **immutable/persistant** (i.e. the **Add** and **Remove** operations don't modify the original data structure). Ideally, the operations would still be `O(1)`, like with a doubly-linked list. I think finger trees could be used for this, but I don't know them well.

Comment: I think what you are looking for has sometimes been called a "quasidictionary"; see Hagerup & Raman's "An Efficient Quasidictionary".

Comment: Note that there are some data structures that are persistent without being immutable; immutability is an implementation technique that achieves "full persistence" and more. See [this chapter by Kaplan that explains the differences between immutable/functional, confluently persistent, fully persistent, and partially persistent.](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~haimk/papers/persistent-survey.ps)

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this with a dictionary, using `myptr a = a`.

You can get $O(\lg n)$ add and remove in an immutable data structure by using a balanced binary search tree. Enumerate will take $O(n)$ time, but the $i$th element can be made available in $O(i)$ time, so your enumerate result can keep up with any consumption of it.

["Confluently Persistent Tries for Efficient Version Control", by Erik D. Demaine, Stefan Langerman, and Eric Price](http://erikdemaine.org/papers/ConfluentTries_Algorithmica/) provides a dictionary that is fully persistent, but not immutable. With it, you can get the same bound on enumerate, and a $O(\lg \lg n)$ bound on add and remove.